# Devexpress Gridview editform how to open in the middle?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, devexpress

Just a simple question, at the minute my editform is opening on the side of the form. I'm just wondering if you can open it in the middle of the form automatically? I can't find option to do so.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this :

```
Private Sub GridView1_EditFormPrepared(sender As Object, e As EditFormPreparedEventArgs) Handles GridView1.EditFormPrepared
    TryCast(e.Panel.Parent, Form).StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
End Sub
```